# Threading / Linq Class list Issue

Tags: c#, linq, class, instance, irc

I've written a very complex multi-server IRC bot recently, and have encountered an issue..
I have stripped down the code as much as I could which can be viewed [here](http://pastie.org/691449.txt).

My issue is that when I call the `Disconnect()` the connection is voided instead of disconnecting and closing the given server. It also just freezes the calling class instead of stopping the correct instance of the Class.

Any help or experience with a similar issue would be greatly appreciated.
Please include code if you can.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to add a break so that this:

```
        foreach (Connection connect in connections)
        {
            if (searching == true)
            {
                if (connect.SERVERID == ServerID)
                {
                    connect.Stop();
                    isFound = true;
                    searching = false;
                    connections.Remove(connect);
                }
            }
        }
```

Becomes:

```
        foreach (Connection connect in connections)
        {
            if (connect.SERVERID == ServerID)
            {
                connect.Stop();
                isFound = true;
                connections.Remove(connect);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Because you are modifying the collection, rather than using the `searching == true` clause.  Much more efficient.

Next, I would change your thread run to look like this:

```
public void Run()
{
    bool WhileOn = true;
    NetworkStream stream;
    string inputLine;
    StreamReader reader;
    try
    {
        using(TcpClient irc = new TcpClient(SERVER, PORT))
        {
        ...
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

So that your connection gets properly disposed.  You should do similarly for your stream.

And finally, I would add an `Abort()` call on your thread in the `Stop` function after a set timeout.  If a TCP socket is blocked by the OS, however, I'm not sure if an abort call will interrupt it...

Comment: This will fail, because you are trying to modify the collection while it is being enumerated: connections.Remove(connect). You will have to use a for or while loop and iterate manually to be able to modify the collection, and you will not be able to use the IEnumerable interface.

Comment: @jrista: No, it should be okay, because after removing the idea it breaks out of the loop; it doesn't iterate again.

Comment: @Xavier:  I'm not sure.  I seem to remember that it is almost impossible to disconnect mid-read.  I would give this a go, though.